# Calculate $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Calculate
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$$
Since both numerator and denominator have the term $x^2+y^2$, so I tried the following solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$x=\rho \cos \theta$$
$$y=\rho\sin \theta$$
Then
$$\begin{aligned}
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{x\sin(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2} &=\lim_{\rho\to0,\theta\to 0}\frac{\rho\cos \theta\sin(\rho^2)}{\rho^2}\\
&=\lim_{\rho\to0,\theta\to 0}\rho \lim_{\rho\to0,\theta\to 0}\cos \theta \lim_{\rho\to0,\theta\to 0}\frac{\sin \rho^2}{\rho^2}\\
& =0\cdot 1\cdot1\\
& =0
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: You only need $\rho\to0$ for $(\rho,\theta)$ to approach to the origin.

Comment: @user170231 Yes, I wrote it in the formula already.